# Cloudant Query android

Tags: android, cloudant

I am currently using Cloudant to store user details when they register for the application as shown below:

```
{
  "_id": "xxx",
  "_rev": "xxx",
  "encrypted_password": "Testing123",
  "username": "testing",
  "email_address": "test@hotmail.com"
}
```

I want to authenticate user by searching through all documents with the same username and password provided by user but my code doesn't seem to work. My code as shown below:

```
public boolean authenticateUser(final String username, final String password) {
    Map<String, Object> query = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
        { put("username", username);
          put("password", password); }
    };

    QueryResult result = indexManager.find(query);

    if(result != null) return true;

    // Reach here if no existing username found
    return false;
}
```

Cloudant Query: https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/query.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document doesn't seem to have a field called "password".